# Ubuntu Server Netplan for Wifi and Ethernet

Tags: server, wireless, netplan

I'm new to Ubuntu server and want set up my netplan so that I can use two different IP addresses for two separate interfaces (Wifi and Ethernet). So far, Ethernet works fine, but I can't get the wifi to connect.

After I run `sudo netplan apply` and check `networkctl`, I can see that my wifi interface has no carrier, and is stuck configuring. Below is the netplan I'm using

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
  enp2s0:
    dhcp4: no
    dhcp6: no
    addresses: [192.168.0.210/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
wifis:
  wlx00265abdaf50:
    dhcp4: no
    dhcp6: no
    addresses: [192.168.0.211/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
    nameservers:
      addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
    access-points:
      "myNetwork":
        password: "myPassword"
```

I'm also unsure of having the two instances of the nameserver bit - I couldn't find an example of someone trying to do the same thing.

Wifi adapter is: D-Link System DWA-130 802.11n Wireless N Adapter(rev.E) [Realtek RTL8191SU]

Comment: Do you have the wpasupplicant package installed?  It is not automatically installed as a dependency of netplan.io since wifi support is optional on servers.

Comment: I just installed it and tried setting it up as per archlinux wiki page. I got this: `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00265abdaf50 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlx00265abdaf50: Failed to initialize driver interface` when I tried initializing. Its possible that the adapter I have is just a piece of garbage.

Comment: Ok I've added an answer which I believe addresses your original question.  If the wifi hardware is not functional with wpasupplicant or with the Linux driver, that's not something I have a solution for.

Answer (score 17):

To use wifi with netplan.io and systemd-networkd, you need to manually install the wpasupplicant package.  It is not automatically installed as a dependency since wifi support is optional on servers.

Comment: tyvm for this! I was trying to get wifi to work for 4 hours!

Comment: thank you @kdelmonte!!!

Answer (score 0):

Also eth and wireless need to be in different subnets eg 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.2.2 as they are different controllers

Comment: This is just wrong. There is no reason why these 2 interfaces can't be on the same subnet, in fact this is VERY common for a laptop connected via wireless and ethernet - I'm typing this on a laptop connected that manner.