# USB WiFi adapter stops working after running netplan apply on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, netplan, realtek-wireless

I would like to set up an active-backup bond for ethernet and WiFi on a freshly installed 20.04 server.  I have installed wpasupplicant and wireless-tools with apt as indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044662/491501).

When I boot the server, my wireless interface works (claims an IP address via DHCP and is pingable).  It doesn't work anymore though when I run `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply`, even if the netplan configuration is unchanged.  I've run both of those with `--debug` and neither provided errors to help troubleshooting so the only way to get WiFi back up is to reboot.  Ethernet works correctly all the time.  The WiFi is a Realtek adapter with USB id 0bda:b720.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enxa0cec8d3f838:
      dhcp4: true
  wifis:
    wlx7cc7099afdf5:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "my-ssid":
          password: "my-password"
  version: 2
```

I have also followed the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081599/491501) to build the driver myself and even after rebooting the problem seems to have persisted, so I'm fairly sure it's not a drivers issue.

Comment: Please see: `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireless.yaml` Is the behavior improved if you add: `renderer: networkd` as shown in the example?

Comment: You should check the output of `dmesg` to see what the kernel says about the driver when reconfiguring, and also the output of `journalctl -u systemd-networkd`.

Comment: @chili555 Adding `renderer: networkd` and rebooting doesn't change anything sadly.

Comment: @slangasek After reconfiguring Netplan, `dmesg | grep rtl` doesn't report anything new.

Comment: @slangasek I checked the generic journalctl and found a wpa_supplicant message with `wlx7cc7099afdf5: Association request to the driver failed`, as well as kernel messages saying `RTL871X: nolinked power save enter`, `RTL871X: RTW_ADAPTIVITY_EN_`, `AUTO, chplan:0x20, Regulation:0,0`, `RTL871X: RTW_ADAPTIVITY_MODE_`, `NORMAL`, `RTL871X: nolinked power save leave`.  This repeats over and over seemingly every about 15 seconds.

Comment: Looking at systemd-networkd specifically, it doesn't show any errors and it says it did connect to my WiFi network after reconfiguring so I suspect it connected and then there was that weird power save enter.

Comment: Which driver is it, exactly? `lsusb` We can try turning off power saving in the driver to see if it helps.

Comment: @chili555 I'm using the RTL8723BU driver.

Comment: I've also tried setting CONFIG_POWER_SAVING to n in the Makefile and rebuilding+reinstalling but to no avail.  Is there some other power saving setting to disable as well?

Comment: Please try: `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and let's look for other clues with: `dmesg | grep wlx` As the results may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com There are several paramters associated with rtl8723bu but little to no documentation to tell us the result.

Comment: I only have a dispatcher.d subdirectory under /etc/NetworkManager (AFAIK Ubuntu Server doesn't use NetworkManager) and `dmesg | grep wlx` shows [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7phYWq3HBS/).